# Displaying Vector in QListView

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I wanted to know what was the best way displaying contents of a vector in a QlistView.I am fairly new to QT hence the question. The vector content changes very fast hence speed is essential. I know you could set models in QT like by setting models

```
QStringList list;
list << "item1" << "item2" << "item3" << "item4" << "item5";
ui.listView->setModel(new QStringListModel(list));
```

How would i do something like that with a vector or a deque type.

Comment: How fast is "very fast"?

Comment: Changes are made to the vector multiple times in a sec

Answer (score 4):

As Matt Philips have mentioned, it can be done by subclassing QAbstractListModel.
However, simpler approach would be to convert QVector/std::vector to QList using built in QList static member:

```
ui.listView->setModel(new QStringListModel(QList<QString>::fromVector(yourQVector)));
```

or

```
ui.listView->setModel(new QStringListModel(QList<QString>::fromStdVector(yourStdVector)));
```

I doubt there would be high overhead due to that conversion, and if you can optimize significantly by sub classing QAbstractListModel...

Comment: so, are you telling me to "change" model every time I press my add button?

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass [QAbstractListModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractlistmodel.html).  This will let you use any data structure you want.  To do so, you will need to implement a couple pure virtual functions, `rowCount()` and `data()`.  Qt's Model/View programming framework is nice but takes some getting used to, it's probably a good idea to read over their [guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html).